# puts line and coloring word that match to variable

Tags: tcl

I'm writing in tcl and want to print the all line and coloring the word or part of the word if it match to variable:

Example:

```
set line "size_cell inst BUFF8"
set cell "BUFF"
```

while printing the line I want to color the word "`BUFF`"
Need your advice please

Comment: Where are you printing the line?

Comment: printing In terminal, writing in "/usr/local/bin/tclsh"

Comment: Printing a word in colour means inserting an escape sequence on either side of the word to make the terminal use colour to render the characters between. Can you modify the `puts` that does the printing, or do you need a solution  that works as a filter?